# Can I use a function in the same module it is defined?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I'm studying from https://medium.com/google-earth/making-it-easier-to-reuse-code-with-earth-engine-script-modules-2e93f49abb13

Let's say this is my module in EE, I would like to export a function but also used it locally.

```
print("hi")
var myprint = function() {
  print("hello")
}
exports.myprint2 = function() {
  print("hello")
}
myprint()
myprint2()
```

How can I use `myprint2` inside this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that article says *Anything a script wants to make available for other scripts to use just gets added to a special global exports variable*. But `exports` is just a (global) scope. So you could do:

```
// attach myprint function to exports variable
exports.myprint = function() {print('hello')}

// call the function
exports.myprint()
```

But I think it's better (and as I've seen is what people does) to do this:

```
// make function
var myprint = function() {print('hello')}
// attach to export var
exports.myprint = myprint
// call function
myprint()
```